# AngularJs inject controller from different domain

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, durandal-2.0

I've been using DurandalJs for an application I've developed where I have a core group of functionality (JS, Html files) saved in domain XXX.  I have a client app (domain YYY) that uses the JS, Html files from domain XXX.  I have DurandalJs set up to inject JavaScript viewModel (and associated view) from a different domain.  It's working really well.

I'm learning AngularJs and am trying to figure out how to do the same.  Is it possible to inject a JavaScript resource from a different domain using AngularJs?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durandal uses requirejs to load resources. Angular do not have a resource loader but you can also use require. You will need to set it up yourself.

http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html

There is no restriction on loading resources from different domains. The only restriction on Cross origin request is when you are using ajax.